# Can an employer revoke a job offer if I have an F on my transcript?

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, recruitment

I'm currently a college senior in engineering and I've accepted a job offer starting after graduation. They require that I send them an official transcript after graduation so they can verify that I earned my degree and that I have atleast a 3.0 GPA. However, I might be getting an F in one of my classes this semester. (I can't drop it because I wouldn't have enough credits to remain a full-time student.) Would the employer look at the F and consider it grounds for revocation, or would they just care that I graduated above a 3.0?

Comment: Why don't you ask your prospective employer? I am voting to close the question based on the fact that you are asking a question that is company specific.

Comment: This seems kind of risky to ask an employer, and I thought people with HR knowledge might have experience with this kind of situation.

Comment: Do you have a written (and signed) offer that states some conditions, or just a verbal understanding?

Comment: Only people with 'HR knowledge' of that specific employer's processes can tell you what they will say, as this is really down to them.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau It's an official e-mail offer. It states conditions required to keep the offer, such as graduating, keeping 3.0, passing background check, etc.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It is an engineering class, but it's not required for graduating. It's just a technical elective so I won't have to retake it next semester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They require that I send them an official transcript after graduation
>   so they can verify that I earned my degree and that I have at least a
>   3.0 GPA. However, I might be getting an F in one of my classes this semester.
>   Would the employer look at the F and consider it grounds for
>   revocation, or would they just care that I graduated above a 3.0?

Employers don't need grounds for revocation (at least not in the US).

Since the requirement in your offer mentioned only the GPA, it seems unlikely that they would care about an F on one particular class (even if part of your major). But if they really want to change their mind about you, they can. And you could change your mind about them, should you choose to do so.

It doesn't sound like it matters much either way at this point. You should do whatever you can do to turn this grade into something better than an F, but otherwise there isn't anything you can do but wait and see.

Only your employer knows for sure how bad this F will be for you.

Comment: Of course if they woudl do this could depend on what the class is too. An F in an elective music class woudl be considered differnt than an F in your major which would be considered differntly than an F in a class you used to sell yourself to them in thw interview. So if the job involves robiotics and you said you were currently enrolled in a robotic class, they might be more likely to revoke than if you failed something unrelated to the job like art history 101.

Answer (score 2):

Can they? Yes, of course. It's not a contract, they can do whatever they want (except for illegal discrimination).

Will they? Probably not. If they stated semi-formally what the conditions are, then they will probably stick with them. However, it's entirely likely your future manager will be told about it. Let them know before your college does.

Comment: Technically I think it is a contract. However they can terminate it, just like they can fire you on your first day if they want, and possibly with some consequences.

Comment: @DJClayworth OP said it was "an official email offer." To me that implies that there has not been a proper "meeting of the minds," and thus no contract, but I'm not a contract lawyer.